# Graphical lags on hybrid graphics laptop

Tags: laptop, void-linux, optimus, i915

I've installed Void Linux on Xiaomi Redmibook Pro 15 2022.
I'm experiencing the strange graphic issue:
In X11 UI works slow. It's even hard to manipulate mouse cursor: it freezes and gets stuck. But if I start video on youtube or run `glxgears` everything starts to work normal.
Also in TTY if I hold any button screen is not been updated at real time. Letters appear after I release the button.
And if I start X, wallpapers and bar appear only after I move cursor or press any button.

I assume that the problem is with Intel driver. Because on kernels 5.13 and 5.15 lswh marks iGPU "UNCLAIMED" and I can't start X, but TTY works properly and letters appears immediately.

Prerequisites:
CPU: i7-12650
dGPU: Nvidia RTX2050
Kernel: 5.18.9 with nvidia-drm.modeset=1 mode setting
WM: Qtile(same thing with i3)
Display: 3200x2000p, 90Hz
No DM.
Also I did not configure DPI yet, UI is very small, but I don`t think it could be a problem.

My ~/.xinitrc

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0  
xrandr --auto   
exec qtile start
```

Output of glmark2

```
GL_VENDOR: Intel
GL_RENDERER: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL GT2) 
GL_VERSION: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.1.3
```

Output of prime-run glmark2

```
GL_VENDOR: NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2050/PCIe/SSE2 
GL_VERSION: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 515.48.07
```

I've installed Ubuntu alongside with Void and everything works out of the box with kernel 5.15.
If needed I can provide any additional information(maybe some outputs from Ubuntu vs Void)

I tried to find any differences in dmesg and lshw outputs between Ubuntu and Void. I did not find something significant, except:

1)Void: `setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:256 nr_cpumask_bits:256 nr_cpu_ids:16 nr_node_ids:1U`
buntu: `setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8192 nr_cpumask_bits:16 nr_cpu_ids:16 nr_node_ids:1`
2) Void dmesg does not contain these lines:

```
[    0.140758] DMA: preallocated 2048 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
[    0.140875] DMA: preallocated 2048 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations 
[    0.140999] DMA: preallocated 2048 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
```

3)In Ubuntu lshw list devices models, but void lists only vendors.

I would really appreciate any suggestion!

There are the files containing outputs of corresponding programs/OS

[dmesg ubuntu](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tc3rnosnggq5gmy/dmesg-ubuntu.txt?dl=0)
[dmesg void](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xycsganoceh8nc/dmesg-void.txt?dl=0)
[lshw-ubuntu](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5kt2cyjp91212k/lshw-ubuntu.txt?dl=0)
[lshw-void](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aboymyzxglxvc3r/lshw-void.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding i915.enable_psr=0 kernel parameter.